# "This page isn't redirecting properly" on one particular site with one particular user

Tags: apache-http-server, django

I administer a web site (https://fury.games) and one of our users is reporting that they cannot load the main page and get the following error:

[image: This page isn't redirecting properly]

I cannot reproduce the error, no other users have reported this error, and the user claims other web sites work for him.

Any ideas?  What can we try?  How might we go about debugging this?  The site is based on apache/django.

Answer (score 2):

Try to have this user :

- Clear the Firefox browser cache
- Clear cookies for your specific domain.

Or the opposite: The user might have refused cookies for your site.

This might also be caused by some extension, so have the user test by
running Firefox in safe mode by
menu button > Help > Troubleshoot Mode… > Restart.